# Cannot add LinqToSQL (dbml) to razor page project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor-pages

I've created "Internet application" with Razor Pages in Visual Studio 2019. Using .net core 3.1.
I cannot add LinqToSQL Classes (dbml) - is that normal?
I wanted to use dbml classes specially for generating classes from tables in db. Maybe there is new way for that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Entity Framework Core to generate model classes from an existing database: https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/walkthroughs/existing-database using either the Package Manager Console (`scaffold-dbcontext`) or the command line tool (`dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold`)

[PMC example]

```
scaffold-dbcontext "Server=.\;Database=MyDb;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer Models MyContext
```

That will generate class files in the *Models* folder for all tables with a primary key in the MyDb database, along with a `DbContext` named *MyContext*.

Answer (score 0):

if this is a fresh install of VS2019 I would try giving this a try. https://www.completecsharptutorial.com/mvc-articles/add-missing-linq-sql-class-vs-2017-2019.php